# iOS 16 SwiftUI List Background Color for Older Apps

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an existing app that has a custom background color for List views. I've used the following in older iOS versions to get this to work.

```
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
```

With iOS 16 the new way to color the background is with

```
List {
        Text("Item 1")
        Text("Item 2")
        Text("Item 3")
    }
    .scrollContentBackground(Color.red)
```

However, my app's Deployment target is iOS 14. When I add the new code above I get an error stating this is only for iOS 16 and later.

The new Lists are now built on UICollectionView instead of UITableView so I tried

```
UICollectionView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
```

This didn't work. When I run iOS 16 in the simulator my custom background color does not show up. Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view modifier to add the background in a specific way depending on if the iOS version is 16 or lower.

In your initializer:

```
if #unavailable(iOS 16, *) {
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

Apply this view modifier to add background when the device is iOS 16

```
@available(iOS 16, *)
struct ListBackgroundModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .scrollContentBackground(Color.red)
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func addBackground() -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16, *) {
            modifier(ListBackgroundModifier())
        }
    }
}
```